# How can I stop regex from messing with font-awesome?

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I need to hide the special character #, using regex I'm this far.
It is now removing break tags, as well as font-awesome characters, and possibly a number of other things.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
<p>#hello ## <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><br>secondline</p>

$("p").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/(#)/g, '');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhdm9f54/)

Comment: Show the contents of the `<p>` tag, please.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `text()` instead of `html()` so it's not your regex but it's jQuery to remove the tags

```
$("p").html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/(#)/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .html() instead of .text() - that'll strip your HTML out:

```
$("p").html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/\#/g,'');
});
```